# Windows compact framework 3.5 combobox dropdown

Tags: compact-framework

I'm updating an existing application that scans barcodes and is written in VB.net running on windows compact framework 3.5. The scanner is a POCKETPC running windows mobile handheld 6.5. I have a combobox `DropDownStyle='DropDown'`. I want to programmatically drop down the box.

I have coded the following:

```
 <DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
                                      ByVal Msg As Integer, _
                                      ByVal wParam As Integer, _
                                      ByVal lParam As Integer) As IntPtr
    End Function
  Const CB_SHOWDROPDOWN As Int32 = &H14F
  SendMessage(cmbVisitoringUnit.Handle, CB_SHOWDROPDOWN, 1, 0)
```

The return code is 1 but no dropdown takes place. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Based on a lot more testing I have done, let me answer my own question. In order for the dropdown message to the combobox to work the combobox must have focus, so the code must first set focus to the control and then send the message to dropdown. There is another quirk with the combobox. If it is dropped down and it losses focus for any reason the control cancels the dropdown and then destroys the event. This leads to an impression that the program is not responding and the user needs to repeat the action again. The only fix I could come up with is to always cancel the dropdown where possible.